# How to find the % difference between 2 numbers that can be positive or negative?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find the % difference between 2 numbers. Sometimes one is negative or both are negative so I think I need to use the Absolute function but I can't find that in AppleScript? Maybe it has an alternative way? I tried something like this but I don't think it will work in all situations. Looking for a better way.

```
set myAvgPrior to 1.47
set myAvg to 1.58

set myAvgDiff to myAvg - myAvgPrior

if myAvg > 0 then
    set myDiffPercent to (1 - (myAvg / myAvgPrior))
else
    set myDiffPercent to (1 - (myAvg / myAvgPrior)) * -1
end if
```

That should give a result of:
0.074829931973

but gives a result of:
-0.074829931973

Comment: I'm not really understanding this. The difference between 1010-1000 is 10. 10÷1000 = .01. Where does 2.01 come from? Also, I don't see how this matches up with your spreadsheet formula, which does not calculate the difference between N1 and N2 and is concerned only with N2's sign. Putting code aside, please express the calculation you would like to achieve.

Comment: It looks like your expected outcome would be correct for `1-(N1/N2)`, i.e. swapping the numerator/denominator (and removing the subtraction from the numerator). Your spreadsheet formula generates ~1.99. If that is your actual target outcome, then leave N1 as a negative (and correct the num/den). Try `set vp to 1 - (n2 / n1)`. Note that I don't think it is correct to describe the spreadsheet formula as a percentage difference. As an aside, it might have been helpful to display more decimal places given the numbers involved.

Comment: Actually the formula (1-(N2/N1))*SIGN(N2) does not work correctly when dealing with 2 positive numbers. It's giving a negative result.
To be more clear, I will edit my example above to include the complete code. Sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: OK @Mockman, I've edited the code. This code works in all examples except when both numbers are positive. Referring to myAvgPrior and myAvg.

Comment: This isn't gonna become a question carousel, is it? What relation does the 'roundthis' handler have with the rest of the problem?

Comment: As mentioned above, this isn't really an applescript issue. The negative outcome is correct. As long as the numerator (avgCurr) is > the denominator (avgPrior), the outcome will always be negative (because diffPercent is > 1 and you're subtracting that value from 1). If you're going to use a ratio (rather than subtraction) then make your calculation and then change the sign appropriately.

Comment: The roundthis has nothing to do with it. I will remove it. It was just part of the larger applescript. I'm not understanding you on the rest though. If I want to see how much 1.58 is in % more than 1.47 then the correct answer would be 1.0748, not -1.0748. The code works in the case of where myAvgPrior is -.5 and myAvg is .5 and gives the right answer of 2 or 200% increase. So I was looking for a formula that worked in both situations but I think it's not possible. I think that can only be done with a logic comparator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128819/discussion-between-mockman-and-steve-torrence).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateNumbers.html

> Several of the JavaScript examples in this chapter call the `Math.abs()` method to get the absolute value of a number. AppleScript does not have an equivalent method.

In the AppleScript examples, Apple use the following as a substitution.

> ```
> set isNegative to theNumber is less than 0
> if isNegative = true then set theNumber to -theNumber
> ```